# Conditional pop window

Tags: android, popupwindow

So I'm still very new to Java and Android programming. The scenario here is that I have created an app which scores the users progress based on how many of their goals they would have achieved at the end of the week. At the end of the scoring process they accumulate points. Based on their accumulated score over several weeks they can acquire trophies. Once they are finish scoring themselves they are taken to an result activity which changes its background image based on the score they achieved for the particular week.  On this very same result activity I would to use a popup window to inform them based on their accumulated points when they have one a trophy. Most of the sample code i have seen use a button to open the pop up. But I would like my to open as soon as the result activity starts and based on whether they met the points for each of the trophies. I tried something myself but as soon as i open the activity it crashed. Please help?!

Comment: A simple generic way of showing a popup would be using AlertDialog (see http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/ )  to make this appear right when you land in the activity all you would have to do is put the AlertDialog code in the onCreate() method

Comment: Hey @HMiller thanks for your suggestion but that is not what i'm looking for. The popup windows appears to be best suited for this since i can design it as you would a layout xml file. as it stands i use the a image of the particular trophy that they won as the background of the popupwindow and a button to close it. Keeping in mind that they a used  depending on the accumulated points may unlock multiple trophies at once.

Comment: You are able to use a custom XML layout with AlertDialog, inserting anything into it including images, buttons, whatever you need